# Create plot from database server side and visualize it on client side

Tags: php, python, mysql, matplotlib, bokeh

I'm currently trying to find the best way of doing this:

We have a python program (client side) we use to upload metrics on a mySQL database on a server and later, via web check it and filter it, etc.

**The problem arises when we try to plot any query from to the database. It's unclear to us what aproach to use.** The main page was made with Joomla in php.

Currently I was looking into python alternatives to run on the server side, somehow capture the query, process the data, create the image and then return it to the client side as an image or as a string to be reconstructed on the client side. But as I have read it seems also possible (and maybe easier) to do the same in PHP or JavaScript which (as I understand it) run on the client side, leaving less to worry about.

Is it that so? Are my assumptions right? Which aproach would you use/pŕefear? Is there some link or info you could give me to continue my search?

I would prefer to do it on Python using something like matplotlib, plotly, bokeh, etc. but as I see it, the problem is not about creating the image, but about comunicating and sending the image information  between server and client.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are trying to plot data from the database in Joomla, I'd use a third party extension such as Plotalot or similar. https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/plotalot/

Comment: I had a look at it but it was no really what we are looking for compared with bokeh. Also as I almost don't know other language other than python I would prefer to stick to it. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it possible to do what you want to with bokeh. I dont know joomla but it think its not that important.

- Check out that part of the bokeh documentation [Embedding Bockeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#)
- then for the server parts in python i would recommend flask to start with.
- You can just prototype your app with one of the [bokeh server apps examples](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#creating-deployable-applications) from the bokeh repo.. there are flask examples too.
- Then you can start to extend the bokeh server app from the examples with a query to your database with [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) or
  [mysql-flask](http://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you! That was very usefull, it points us to some direction! I'm currently reading about embedding Bokeh and Bokeh server! I have heard of Flask but never really diged into it, I guess it could be that time now. Thanks again!